# Which is the best package for econometrics in java?

Tags: java, regression, linear-regression

I was wondering if there is a Java toolkit that deals with econometrics. I am aware of Jet ( http://jet.codehaus.org/) and other regression packages (like http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Regression.html or the apache math package) but nothing seems to be complete.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be able use the R language, which has [good support for econometrics][3].

[Renjin](http://code.google.com/p/renjin/) is a new implementation of R on top of the JVM and so should inter-operate well with Java.  It's still under development so may not suit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I will try that. Right now I was using R from the command line (through java system calls) since JRI is a disappointment.